# XCUITest Element Snapshot Fails Blinking Cursor

Tags: xcuitest, fbsnapshottestcase, xcuiscreenshot

We are using FBSnapshottestcase to take snapshots as part of our XCUITest cases.  We have a ScrollView that has an UITextField.  We type text into the text field and take a snapshot to verify the element behaves appropriately with text entered (a clear button appears).  The problem we encounter is that when you type into the text field a blinking cursor appears.  The tests will fail or pass depending on the state of the blinking cursor when the snapshot is taken.  Is there a way to disable the blinking cursor for a XCUITest?

Comment: end text with / . I think it will remove blink cursor. I had same problem. I forget actual code. let me search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devs added this to the AppDelegate file so that when we are running the test scheme it would do this:

```
#if LOCAL
     if CommandLine.arguments.contains("--UITests") {
        UITextField.appearance().tintColor = .clear
     }
#endif
```

This hide the cursor then for the tests.

You can then you 
`app.launchArguments` to pass "--UITests"

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/1500477-launcharguments

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set an optional parameter `tolerance` in `FBSnapshotVerifyView` call.

For example, if it is set to `0.01` and images are equal by 99% (counting in pixels) or more, then test will not fall.